# Manually Call a C++ Object's Initializer in C

Tags: c++, c, initialization, termios

I am working on a small application that was written in C++ and would like to use on my platform. Unfortunately, our cross-compile toolchain only (reliably) provides a C compiler. I looked at the application, and it is fairly simple and only uses C++-specific idioms in a few places, so I thought I'd just convert it to C code by hand.

I bumped across one line that I'm not sure how to handle. The code is using Termios to open a new port to talk to a TTY stream, and initializes the Termios struct using the `new` keyword.

```
termios *settings = new termios();
```

As I understand it, the `new` keyword, in addition to allocating the appropriate memory, calls the object's initializer. In C, after I allocate memory with `malloc`, can I manually call the initializer? Do I need to?

I have a feeling that I'm misunderstanding something obvious / fundamental or that I'm looking at this all wrong. I'm not very accustomed to C++ code.

edit: I seem to have caused some confusion. The line of code above is creating a new termios struct as defined in `termios.h`, part of the standard libraries on most implementations of C.

Comment: "In C, after I allocate memory with malloc, can I manually call the initializer?" No you can't. "Do I need to?" It depends on the object.

Comment: Show the definition of `termios`.

Comment: @Chad The question is full of C: See the definition in in the manpage of termios

Comment: If this is `struct termios` from `termios.h`, there is no initializer. You don't need to do anything special. Just allocate `struct termios by whatever means you fancy.

Comment: You might look at glib (See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib)

Comment: You also may not have to use dynamic allocation. better declare it as a local variable and give the address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
termios *settings = new termios();
```

allocates memory for a `termios` object and [value-initializes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) it. Since `termios` is a POD, the equivalent C would be

```
struct termios* settings = calloc(1, sizeof(*settings));
```

or

```
struct termios* settings = malloc(sizeof(*settings));
memset(settings, 0, sizeof(*settings));
```

and of course the equivalent of `delete settings` would be `free(settings)`.

Comment: Thank you! Does "POD" mean "piece of data", meaning "it's just a structure, it doesn't have an initializer"?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Yes, "POD" is an acronym for "Plain Old Data". Any C `struct` would be a POD in C++. ([See the description of the `is_pod` trait at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod))

Comment: Thank you. This answers exactly what I meant to ask in my question; I'm sorry that I wasn't able to express myself more clearly.

Comment: Actually, I believe it would be `calloc(1, sizeof(*settings))`. `calloc` takes the number of elements and the size of each element. Odd that it's different than `malloc`, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating a function

```
termios *new_termios()
```

that would combine malloc with constructor code. After that, do not use malloc to allocate `termios`.

Answer (score 1):

> "In C, after I allocate memory with malloc, can I manually call the initializer?

Unfortunately, you can't.

> Do I need to?"

It really depends on the definition of `termios` objects. Basically, what `malloc` does is simply allocate a chunk of memory. That is, it doesn't do any initializations and inner memory allocations like a constructor does.

What I do in these situations:

I create C wrapper functions for my C++ objects with the help of opaque pointers. For example in order to call the constructor of a C++ object I would create a C++ wrapper for C in a `.cpp` file:

```
void* create_termios() { return new termios(); }
void  destroy_termios(void *obj) { delete obj; }
// other wrapper functions for termios
```

And then I would interface these functions in C with a `.h` file:

```
extern "C" {
    void* create_termios();
    void  destroy_termios(void *obj);
    // declare any other necessary wrappers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `termios` is the name of a `struct` related to [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) function, so better not use that `termios` name in a Linux or POSIX program in C (i.e. avoid naming your types with usual types provided by system libraries).

BTW you should consider using some *existing* terminal IO library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) or [readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/)

At last, if you insist in having your own `termios` structure or class (which is practically a very bad idea, choose some other name) managed by your C++ library to be called by C, you should wrap its allocator+constructor &  destructor+deallocator like this.

```
extern "C" struct termios* make_my_termios () {
   struct termios* ts = new termios;
   return ts;
}

extern "C" void destroy_my_termios(struct termios* ts) {
   delete ts;
}
```

And if you just use the genuine `struct termios*` (from [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html)) in your C++ library, just keep it as it is...

Comment: sorry for the confusion. the termios in question is **the** termios, not a custom struct that happens to have the same name (which would be a bad idea indeed!).